# Word for person interested in latest technology programming-wise

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe a person who is really interested in learning new aspects and new things in a specific programming language? (We could call this person a seeker.)

Comment: Enthusiast maybe?

Comment: Have you considered "technophile"? I'm having a hard time deciding whether "Here's something for all you Java technophiles: Oracle recently announced..." sounds natural.

Comment: Newly coined by me; a 'blog worm', (like a book worm, but for the web).

Comment: @Mitch - IMHO technophile is too generic - this person specific has an interest in the *latest developments* of a particular *programming language*. A technophile just has a general interest in technology...

Comment: @CJM Yes the "latest developments" part might render "technophile" an inadequate choice, but I was trying to see if using the programming language as a noun adjunct as in "Java technophiles" sounded natural, and you seem not to have noticed this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wikipedia suggests:

> [**Neophile**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neophile): A lover of new things, especially new technology.

Answer (score 7):

Wiktionary’s [*geek*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geek) would be a perfect fit, if you don't mind the negative implication some see in the word:

> A person intensely interested in a
>   particular field or hobby, generally
>   at the expense of broader social
>   interaction. Often used with an
>   attributive noun.

Comment: But the thing is _geek_ connotes expert knowledge, for the most part.

Comment: No negative connotations these day, thanks to **Geek Chic**. Remember, the bible said that the 'Geeks shall inherit the earth'... or something like that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, yeah you are right, changed it. @CJM, didn't know about **Geek Chic**, and I would say, I may not be alone in this case.

Comment: One would sometimes see "dork" stand in for "geek" for this usage, e.g. "film dork" and "music dork".

Comment: @Eldros - It's a 'fact' in the UK, and is similar in the US, and according to friend, it's pretty much the same in your homeland too. Clearly, one's perception may depend on age, but geeks, similarly emos, have been quite fashionable for some time.

Comment: @JM - don't confuse *geek* with *dork*: Dorks are quirky, silly and/or stupid, socially inept, whereas modern Geeks tend to be technical/creative/intellectual and perhaps outside the mainstream. The two do not generally even overlap.

Comment: Stay away from geek.  Being a geek also involves biting the heads off of chickens at carnivals.

Comment: Geek is certainly the closest you'll get, given that the word tends to be prefixed by the domain in question, *coding geek* perhaps, *programming language geek* sounds too long, *technogeek* is the cover-all.

Answer (score 7):

'Early Adopter' perhaps? Or an 'Evangelist'?

I once heard someone called a 'State of the Art-ist'!

Edit: not a noun, but might they also be described as 'always on the bleeding edge'?

Comment: @Jimi - not so. Or not necessarily. The bleeding edge is considered either to be either the front of the cutting edge or even in front of the cutting edge, and it perfectly appropriate for this phrase. Cutting edge works too, but the assertion that it 'should be' the cutting edge is wrong.

Comment: I stand corrected. I should check my facts next time before boldly making such an erroneous claim. Thanks, again. I've gained a new one.

Comment: Now "cutting edge" looks cliche in comparison. Wish I'd known of "bleeding edge" before turning in a recent essay.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a noun right away, but there are quite a few adjectives: *curious*, *inquisitive*, *studious*.

And then there's always [*early adopter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_adopter), but that has a slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The closest word I can think of to suit your definition would be *enthusiast*. An enthusiast, though, is not necessarily interested in *learning* new aspects.

Answer (score 1):

"bleeding edge specialist" springs to mind, though it's not exactly elegant or simple.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Technologically Adaptive"...?

Comment: This answer could be more helpful if you tell us more about why you think this phrase is a good fit. You might define it or give an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I hear the most in my workplace is **cutting-edge**.

> at the latest or most advanced stage of development; innovative or
>   pioneering.

Comment: Please provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from, and a link if available.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.